# jQuery not working with cakephp 2.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am currently working on a project where i wanna implement jQuery to cakephp 2.0.

I have followed the guide at: 
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/js.html

i.e. I have downloaded jquery-1.8.1.js (also tried the .min.js file) and put it in app/webroot/js.
In the default layout file i have added

```
echo $this->Html->script('jquery');
```

and just before the end of the body tag i have added

```
echo $this->Js->writeBuffer();
```

In my controller i have added

```
public $helpers = array('Js' => array('Jquery'));
```

When i reload my page and check the source code I see that the link to the jQuery file works correctly. 
But when I try to add a simple script (just adding an alert) like this (in the view file):

```
$alert = $this->Js->alert('Hey there');
```

nothing happens...

Any kind person out there that might have any suggestion to what I do wrong? 
I have spent hours looking looking at the internet and following different guides but still can get a simple thing as an alert working.

Comment: do you also echo the $alert then? my guess: you are not even printing this line. also, why not using firebug to properly debug js? then it would tell you exactly what the problem is - if its js related.

Comment: if i echo the $alert it just prints alert("Hey there"); but I dont get a pop-up...

Comment: better than not printing it, isnt it? is it encapsulated in a <script> tag? you cant just throw around with js outside of the js scope.

Comment: First of all i appreciate your help!

if i write: 
<script>
<?
$alert = $this->Js->alert('Hey there');
echo $alert;
?>
</script>
i do get the pop-up window but i thought the point of having the Js helper was so i wouldnt need to write all that, or am i wrong?

Comment: thats why the examples show how to use it inside other Js methods. otherwise you could just write plain js, of course.

Comment: Forget the Js helper and directly write jquery code. You will find it in adequate anyways when you want to do slightly more complex things.

Comment: I am facing the same problem, if you have solved this and do have spare time, kindly help me.

Answer (score 3):

According to CakePHP 2.0 documentation: "by default, alert does not buffer, and returns the script snippet."

So by default:

```
echo $this->Js->alert('Hey there'); // outputs alert("Hey there");
```

To override this behaviour and add the script to the buffer:

```
echo $this->Js->alert('Hey there', true);
```

To write the buffer (commonly right before `</body>`):

```
echo $this->Js->writeBuffer();
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can use scriptBlock:

```
$jscript = "alert('Hey there!');";
echo $this->Html->scriptBlock($jscript, array('inline'=>false));
```